# SPARK Job returning ExitCodeException exitCode=1 : Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop-yarn

I keep getting  ExitCodeException exitCode=1: when trying to run the spark job with large data set.

```
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
)] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.removeExecutor(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(YarnSchedulerBackend.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        ... 11 more
```

My Config :

```
30 Slaves of r3.8xLarge
spark.driver.cores  30
spark.driver.memory 200g
spark.executor.cores    7
spark.executor.instances    240
spark.executor.memory   40g
spark.memory.fraction   0.7
```

I have a df = [CUSTOMER_ID ,itemType, eventTimeStamp, valueType, value ]

```
    +-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+--------------------+
    | CUSTOMER_ID | itemType  | valueType   | value  | eventTimeStamp     |
    +-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+
    | 1           |  rent     |  dvd        |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
    | 1           |  rent     |  dvd        |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
    | 1           | buy       |  tv         |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
    | 1           |  rent     |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
    | 1           |   buy     |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
    | 1           | buy       |  movie      |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
    +-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get the result as :

```
     CUSTOMER_ID : 1
        totalValue  : 72 --- group by based on id
        itemTypeMap : {"rent" : 3, "buy" : 3} --- group by based on id
        valueTypeMap : {"dvd" : 2, "tv" : 1, "movie" : 3 } --- group by based on id
        itemTypeForDay : {"rent: 2, "buy" : 2 }  --- group By based on id and dayofmonth(col("eventTimeStamp"))  atmost 1 type per day
```

My Code :

```
       val temp = df.groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID").agg(
              collectAsList(df("itemType")).alias("itemCount"),
              collectAsList(df("valueType")).alias("valueTypeCount"),
              sum("value") as "totalValues")


       val stage1  =  temp.withColumn("valueTypeMap", count_by_value(col("valueTypeCount")))
              .withColumn("itemTypeMap", count_by_value(col("itemCount")))
              .drop("itemCount")
             .drop("valueTypeCount")

       val toMap = udf { (typ: String, count: Int) => Map(typ -> count) }

       val count_by_value = udf {( value :scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => if (value == null) null else  value.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)}

       val collectAsList = new CollectListFunction(StringType)


       import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{dayofmonth, countDistinct}



       val stage2 = df.groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID", "itemType")
              .agg(countDistinct(dayofmonth(col("eventTimeStamp"))) as "daysPeritemType")
              .withColumn("itemTypeForDay", toMap(col("itemType"), col("daysPeritemType")))
              .groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID").agg(CombineMaps(col("itemTypeForDay")) as "resultMap")

       val result = stage1.join(stage2, stage1("CUSTOMER_ID") === stage2("CUSTOMER_ID"))
              .drop(stage2("CUSTOMER_ID"))

        TestPairFucntion.saveAsTempFile(convertToRDD(result))
```

Util classes :

```
     case class Data(totalValue: Long, typeCount: Map[String,Int], typeForDay: Map[String,Int] ,itemCount : Map[String,Int]) extends Serializable

         def convertToRDD(result : DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {

            val tempFile = result.map( {
              r => {
                val customerId = r.getAs[String]( "CUSTOMER_ID" )
                val totalValue = r.getAs[Long]( "totalValue" )

                val typeCount = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "typeCount" )
                val itemCount = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "itemCount" )
                val typeForDay = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]]( "typeForDay" )


                val features = Data( totalValue, typeCount, typeForDay, itemCount)

                val jsonString = JacksonUtil.toJson( features )

                (customerId, jsonString)
              }
            } )

            return tempFile
          }

    class CollectListFunction[T] (val colType: DataType) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

      def inputSchema: StructType =
        new StructType().add("inputCol", colType)

      def bufferSchema: StructType =
        new StructType().add("outputCol", ArrayType(colType))

      def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(colType)

      def deterministic: Boolean = true

      def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
        buffer.update(0, new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[T])
      }

      def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
        val list = buffer.getSeq[T](0)
        if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
          val sales = input.getAs[T](0)
          buffer.update(0, list:+sales)
        }
      }

      def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
        buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getSeq[T](0) ++ buffer2.getSeq[T](0))
      }

      def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
        buffer.getSeq[T](0)
      }
    }



    object CombineMaps extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
      override def inputSchema: StructType = new StructType().add("map", dataType)
      override def bufferSchema: StructType = inputSchema
      override def dataType: DataType = MapType(StringType, IntegerType)
      override def deterministic: Boolean = true

      override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer.update(0 , Map[String, Int]())

      override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
        val before = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
        val toAdd = input.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
        val result = before ++ toAdd
        buffer.update(0, result)
      }

      override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = update(buffer1, buffer2)

      override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = buffer.getAs[Map[String, Int]](0)
    }
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Do you have one task that is way slower than the others?

Comment: @LiMuBei   TestPairFucntion.saveAsTempFile(convertToRDD(result)) this one.

Comment: No, I meant is there in any stage a few tasks that take way longer than the other tasks? That would indicate some skew in the data which might be the reason for the futures timing out.

Comment: @LiMuBei  Yeah the saveAsTempFile has 80K partition and it is getting stuck in there. I tried to increase roc timeout but still same error